PJSIP reports "codec parsed 0 frames"
I have these warnings in my logfile:
strm0xb400007c02efd010 codec parsed 0 frames
Inspecting the source code (stream.c) shows that:
status = pjmedia_codec_parse(stream->codec, (void*)payload, payloadlen, &ts, &count, frames);

returned PJ_SUCCESS, but count was set 0.
Any valid reason as why this could be happening? Is there something that I should notice on the sender side?
